# ngnix hang the request: upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream

Tags: java, http, nginx

the browser request keep pending status all the time when the backend service return reponse with 4-digit status code(eg.8888), 
Nginx error log is ： 
upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream, client: 100.203.20.332, server: gateway.hotels.cn, request: "GET /mobile/activity/qrcode HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://192.168.0.100:8080/mobile/activity/qrcode", host: "gateway.hotels.cn"

but there is no this problem with 3 digit status code(eg. 888) .

Without going through nginx,  there is no any problems when direct hit backend service return whether 4 digit status code or 3 digit code

## nginx.conf file

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$http_host"  "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$uid_got" "$uid_set" "$cookie_lvsessionid" "$upstream_response_time" "$request_time"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  300;
    open_file_cache max=65535 inactive=20s;
    server_tokens off;
    server_tag nginx2;
    server_info off;
    client_max_body_size        60m;
    client_header_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_timeout 60m;
    client_body_timeout 60m;
    proxy_buffer_size          16k;
    proxy_buffers              16 80k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    80k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 280k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_cache_path /var/data/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=NAME:600m inactive=60m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types  text/css application/x-javascript application/json text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    server {
            listen  80;
            server_name gateway.hotels.cn;
            access_log  /var/log/nginx/gateway.access.log main;
            return 301  https://$server_name$request_uri;

            proxy_headers_hash_max_size 51200;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 6400;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header remote-port $remote_port;

            include /etc/nginx/allow-origin.conf;
    }
    server {
            listen  443 ssl http2;
            server_name gateway.hotels.cn;
            access_log  /var/log/nginx/gateway.access.log main;
            error_log  /var/log/nginx/gateway-error.log;

            proxy_headers_hash_max_size 51200;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 6400;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header remote-port $remote_port;

            ssl         on;
            ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/keys/hotels.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/keys/hotels.key;

            charset utf-8;
            sendfile on;
            send_timeout 300;
            underscores_in_headers on;
            include /etc/nginx/allow-origin.conf;


            location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100:8080/;
            }
    }
}
```